# Adding bootstrap into jira servlet plugin

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jira, velocity, jira-plugin

I have a very simple Servlet Plugin and I want to add bootstrap on it.

First, I must to add all Bootstrap resources in my Atlassian-plugin.xml:

```
<web-resource key="purism-resources" name="purism Web Resources">
<dependency>com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs</dependency>
<resource type="download" name="purism.css" location="/css/purism.css"/>
<resource type="download" name="purism.js" location="/js/purism.js"/>
<resource type="download" name="jquery.min.js" location="/js/jquery.min.js"/>

<!-- comeco bootstrap-->
<resource type="download" name="bootstrap.js" location="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"/>
<resource type="download" name="bootstrap.min.js" location="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
<resource type="download" name="bootstrap-treeview.js" location="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-treeview.js"/>
<resource type="download" name="bootstrap-treeview.min.js" location="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-treeview.min.js"/>
<resource type="download" name="npm.js" location="/bootstrap/js/npm.js"/>
<resource type="download" name="jquery.js" location="/bootstrap/js/jquery.js"/>
<resource type="download" name="bootstrap.css" location="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<resource type="download" name="bootstrap.min.css" location="/bootstrap/css/purism.css"/>
<resource type="download" name="bootstrap-theme" location="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css"/>
<resource type="download" name="bootstrap-theme.min.css" location="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
<resource type="download" name="bootstrap-treeview.min.css" location="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-treeview.min.css"/>
<resource type="download" name="res/" location="/bootstrap"/>
<!-- fim bootstrap-->

<resource type="download" name="images/" location="/images"/>
<context>purism</context>
```

p.s. all those patches are correct. 
And than, from my servlet that will render my velocity, the famous pagebuilderservice:

```
    @Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    pageBuilderService.assembler().resources().requireWebResource("com.plugins.purism.purism:purism-resources");
    templateRenderer.render(TREE_VIEWER, resp.getWriter());
}
```

My velocity (very simple):

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>teste</title>
    <!-- Required Stylesheets -->
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Required Javascript -->
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-treeview.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="tree"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

My problem is, i got those erros when i try to use:
$('#tree').treeview({data: getTree()});

```
GET http://localhost:8080/plugins/servlet/res/jquery.js 
treeservlet:15 GET http://localhost:8080/plugins/servlet/res/bootstrap-treeview.js 
treeservlet:5 GET http://localhost:8080/plugins/servlet/bootstrap.css 
treeservlet:11 GET http://localhost:8080/plugins/servlet/res/bootstrap.css 
treeservlet:8 GET http://localhost:8080/plugins/servlet/jquery.js 
treeservlet:9 GET http://localhost:8080/plugins/servlet/bootstrap-treeview.js 
VM1591:3 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).treeview is not a function(…)
```

Anybody knows how can I add Bootstrap resources into Jira Plugin Servlet?

Thank you!

Comment: P.s. When I add javascript resources manually in browser, it works!

Comment: Try removing `<!-- Required Stylesheets -->
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Required Javascript -->
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-treeview.js"></script>` as the `requireWebResource` method should add these in the head for you with the correct path.

Comment: Thank you!! it worked!! I also added <meta name="decorator" content="atl.admin"> in my velocity.

Comment: Good spot! I completely forgot about the meta tags. I've added an answer to explain why I believe this works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove

```
<!-- Required Stylesheets -->
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Required Javascript -->
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-treeview.js"></script>
```

from your Velocity as we're trying to achieve this by calling `requireWebResources()` in order to get the correct path to the resources. Having these lines would duplicate it.

As you mentioned in your comment, add a meta tag for a [decorator](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/latest-updates/developer-changes-for-older-jira-versions/preparing-for-jira-5-0/changes-to-markup-css-and-decorators-in-jira-5-0) (these were changed in JIRA 5.0 and I believe are still relevant to  JIRA 6 and JIRA 7 (OP tested)).

For example, if you wanted a page to have the JIRA navigation bar at the top (the header) and the footer, use

```
<meta name="decorator" content="atl.general">
```

In your case, you've gone for an admin page style:

```
<meta name="decorator" content="atl.admin">
```

If you want to style the page completely yourself and have no Atlassian branding or styling on it, use:

```
<meta name="decorator" content="blank">
```

**Why this works (I think!)**

If you don't add a decorator, web resources you declare using     `requireWebResource("com.plugins.purism.purism:purism-resources");` won't be added to the `<head>` element. This is because nothing will call the `drainIncludedResources()` method that will add the required resources to the Velocity template. Adding the decorator will call  `drainIncludedResources()`***** in order to add the resources required to style the page in the Atlassian style. This call also adds any web resources declared to be required by calling `requireWebResource()`.

*The documentation for [RequiredResources](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/44073022/) says the method JIRA calls is `drainIncludedResources()` but I can't find any documentation for this. The functionality should be the same as this [includeResources()](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/plugin/navigation/HeaderFooterRendering.html#includeResources-javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter-) method.

Comment: Thank you Sam, I cant upvote your answer but I hope this is enough.

About this work, i think it's related with <context>purism</context>. When you add decorator, maybe a context is created.

Comment: P.s. This (META Decorator) is working in JIRA 7.0 (im using 7.1.2)

Comment: I've added that you tested this with JIRA 7 to the answer. I think the context is primarily there to group resources together and apply them in different places. You could, for example, put `<context>atl.general</context>` in your web resource declaration in the atlassian-plugin.xml and your resources will be included on every page where `<meta name="decorator" content="atl.general">` is in the head for the Velocity template. I'm not sure the context is created when a decorator is added. Either way, I'm glad it sorted your issue!

Comment: Didn't you face the problem where Bootstrap CSS overrides JIRA styles so when using `atl.general` or `atl.admin` decorators, parts of the native UI appear messed up?

Comment: I don't think I ever actually tried this using Bootstrap CSS. I'd guess you're right though, some of the ID's/classes used in the templates for JIRA will probably be the same as ones used in Bootstrap. I think it all depends what gets added to the generated HTML last: the link element to the Bootstrap CSS or the link element(s) to the Atlassian CSS provided by the decorator.

Comment: @Sam it's worth nothing that using decorator `blank` doesn't remove JIRA stylesheets from the page. All it does is it removes default page elements such as header and footer (that are styled using AUI) but the stylesheets are still loaded. So scenarios where AUI CSS classes clash with 3rd party UI framework can still happen.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a way to not load default JIRA resources (similar to what decorator `none` does) but still load custom plugin resources defined via `web-resource` in `atlassian-plugin.xml`...